Develop a dialogue system for a game in html 5 canvas
similar to rpgs with a popup window and text options. like stardew valley. Are there any common approaches to implement this?

This question is very broad at the moment. A volunteer usually won't design the whole feature for you here. Is there a specific aspect of implementing this that you need help with, or a particular step of the process you're stuck on?
